# Strange errors with windows 8.1 SDK

Tags: c++, windows

I installed VS 2013 and after converting my project previusly compiled with VS 2012 and winSDK 8.0(or 7.1 not sure), I now tried to compile it with VS 2013 and winSDK 8.1 and got the following errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h(1308):
>   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION'
>       1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h(1308): error C4430: missing type specifier
>   - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>       1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h(1316): error C2143: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before '*'

List goes on...
I also tried some other projects and got the same errors.

**EDIT**

It seems my winsdk 8.1 is trashed or something because it shows those errors as soon as I include #windows.h.

```
#include <Windows.h>


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{
}
```

Comment: Can you make a small, simple example program that exhibits this behavior (a.k.a. a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) and edit the question to include that program?

Comment: EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION appears on line 1307, not 1308.  Not good.  Falls apart at the _Function_class() macro it seems.

Comment: As odd as it sounds, put this at the top of your  file: `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>` *before* including Windows.h. Just curious to see what happens.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, still same errors.

Comment: I had the same problem. The reason was that I introduced a space in a macro in winnt.h. #define N TSYSCALLAPI DECLSPEC_IMPORT instead of #define N TSYSCALLAPI DECLSPEC_.  The best time saving option is to delete windows kits and get a new one.